# PDO Exception 42000

Tags: sql, pdo

I have tried to insert data into my database but I keep getting this error that I can't figure out. Been all over the forums and cant find an answer so I thought I would post.

Full error for reference.

[error](http://puu.sh/j5cOj/09497ba6ae.jpg)

Code:

```
    <?php
    $Records = $connect->query('SELECT COUNT(ID) as counted FROM listings;');
    $fetchdata = $Records->fetch();
    $i = $fetchdata['counted'];
    $i++;
    $name = 'hold';
    $OS = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $type = $_POST['type'];
     $loc = $_POST['loc'];
     $desc = $_POST['desc'];
     $prem = $_POST['premium'];

     }

    if($name != 'hold'){
     $sql = "INSERT INTO listings (name,premium,location,type,desc,onsite,ID,paymentid) VALUES (:Name,:Prem,:Loc,:Type,:Desc,:Onsite,:ID,:Paymentid);";
     $Appquery = $connect->prepare($sql);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Name', $name, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Prem', $prem, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Loc', $loc, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Type', $type, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Desc', $desc, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Onsite', $OS, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':ID', $i, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $Appquery->bindParam(':Paymentid', $i, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

     $Appquery->execute();
     header("Location: index.php"); 
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `desc` and `type` [are reserved MySQL keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html). Just quote them as:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO listings (name,premium,location,`type`,`desc`,onsite,ID,paymentid) VALUES (:Name,:Prem,:Loc,:Type,:Desc,:Onsite,:ID,:Paymentid);";
//                                                  ^    ^ ^    ^
```